# ExecuteNonQuery() not responding/working

Tags: c#, database, database-connection, executenonquery

I have a problem with my application, that had worked before. My application connects to an Oracle database. At the moment I want to add a new account. In my C# code I have a database class with the following method:

```
public void AddAccount(string name, string addres, string username, string password)
{
    string query = "insert into account(id, name, addres, username, password, datecreated, game_id) values(account_seq.nextval,:name,:addres,:username,:password, sysdate, 1)";

        OpenConnection();
        try
        {
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, connection);
            OracleParameter[] parameters = new OracleParameter[]
            {
                new OracleParameter(":name", name),
                new OracleParameter(":addres", addres),
                new OracleParameter(":username", username),
                new OracleParameter(":password", password)
            };
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + username + "! You can now login with your new account.");
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        CloseConnection();
    }
```

Here is my `OpenConnection` method that connects me to the database:

```
public bool OpenConnection()
            {
                try
                {
                    connection = new OracleConnection();
                    String user = "***";
                    String pw = "***";
                    connection.ConnectionString = "User Id=" + user + ";Password=" + pw + ";Data Source=" + " //localhost:1521/xe" + ";"; //orcl is de servicename (kan anders zijn, is afhankelijk van de Oracle server die geinstalleerd is. Mogelijk is ook Oracle Express: xe
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Connectie met database");
                    connection.Open();
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
                    return true;

                }
                catch (OracleException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

And as last here is the method from my main form where I want to add a new member:

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    database = new Database();
    database.AddAccount(tbRegisterName.Text, tbRegisterAddress.Text, tbRegisterUsername.Text, tbRegisterPassword.Text);
    database.AddAchievement1();
}
```

My connection with the database works and I tested it with a messagebox. Also from my form everything works. The strange thing is that it won't get past the `Command.ExecuteNonQuery();` It does not give an error or anything. It just hangs/crashes.

All the data within the parameters is right and like I said, it has worked before. So I find it very strange that it does not work now. I haven't changed anything crucial.

From my experience an `ExecuteNonQuery()` method can fail if you have no Inet connection or the database is not connected to the application. But none of these are true. So I was wondering if any of you experts know where the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

If `OpenConnection()` fails you get no feedback in `AddAccount()`.

Try:

```
public void AddAccount(string name, string addres, string username, string password)
{       ....
      if (OpenConnection())
      {
         ///continue
      }
      else
      {
        ///log error
      }
}
```

This approach  can specify where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're using the parameters wrong.
Remove the colons before the variable names like that:

```
new OracleParameter ("name", name);
new OracleParameter ("addres", addres); // etc
```

But leave the colons in the query.

Here's some info on this topic:
[MSDN:System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters.aspx)
[MSDN:System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.aspx)